# CUDA - median filter implementation does not produce desired results

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, cuda

I have been trying to implement the algorithm for the median filter presented in the Wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter#2D_median_filter_pseudo_code

To the best of my knowledge, I know that what I have implemented is right. However, when I view the results, I cannot seem to get an output which is similar to the output produced by the `median blur` function in OpenCV. At the present moment, I am not concerned about speeding up my code by using shared memory or texture memory. I would just like to get things working first. The size of my input image is `1024 x 256` pixels.

**What am I doing wrong? Is there a thread leak in my code?** I know that I should use shared memory to prevent the global read because currently, I am reading data from the global memory a lot.

http://snag.gy/OkXzP.jpg -- the first image is the input, second image is my algorithm result, and the third is the openCV `medianblur` function result. Ideally, I would like my algorithm to output the same result as the `medianblur` function.

This is all the code that I have written:

**kernel implementation**

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "device_functions.h"
#include "highgui.h"
//#include "opencv2/core/imgproc.hpp"
//#include "opencv2/core/gpu.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// includes, project

#include "cufft.h"
#include "cublas_v2.h"
#include "CUDA_wrapper.h"   // contains only func_prototype for function take_input()


// define the threads and grids for CUDA
#define BLOCK_ROWS 32
#define BLOCK_COLS 16

// define kernel dimensions
#define KERNEL_DIMENSION 3
#define MEDIAN_DIMENSION 3
#define MEDIAN_LENGTH 9

// this is the error checking part for CUDA
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

// create two vars for the rows and cols of the image
    int d_imgRows;
    int d_imgCols; 

__global__ void FilterKernel (unsigned short *d_input_img, unsigned short *d_output_img, int d_iRows, int d_iCols)

{  
    unsigned short window[BLOCK_ROWS*BLOCK_COLS][KERNEL_DIMENSION*KERNEL_DIMENSION];

    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;   

    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.x;

    if(x>d_iCols || y>d_iRows)
        return;

    window[tid][0]= (y==0||x==0) ? 0.0f : d_input_img[(y-1)*d_iCols+(x-1)];
    window[tid][1]= (y==0) ? 0.0f : d_input_img[(y-1)*d_iCols+x]; 
    window[tid][2]= (y==0||x==d_iCols-1) ? 0.0f : d_input_img[(y-1)*d_iCols+(x+1)];
    window[tid][3]= (x==0) ? 0.0f : d_input_img[y*d_iCols+(x-1)];
    window[tid][4]= d_input_img[y*d_iCols+x];
    window[tid][5]= (x==d_iCols-1) ? 0.0f : d_input_img[y*d_iCols+(x+1)];
    window[tid][6]= (y==d_iRows-1||x==0) ? 0.0f : d_input_img[(y+1)*d_iCols+(x-1)];
    window[tid][7]= (y==d_iRows-1) ? 0.0f : d_input_img[(y+1)*d_iCols+x];
    window[tid][8]= (y==d_iRows-1||x==d_iCols-1) ? 0.0f : d_input_img[(y+1)*d_iCols+(x+1)];

   __syncthreads();

    // Order elements 
    for (unsigned int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
        // Find position of minimum element
        int min=j;
        for (unsigned int l=j+1; l<9; ++l)
            if (window[tid][l] < window[tid][min])
                min=l;

        // Put found minimum element in its place
        const unsigned char temp=window[tid][j];
        window[tid][j]=window[tid][min];
        window[tid][min]=temp;

        __syncthreads();
    }

    d_output_img[y*d_iCols + x] = (window[tid][4]);

}

void take_input(const cv::Mat& input, const cv::Mat& output)
{

    unsigned short *device_input; 
    unsigned short *device_output;

    size_t d_ipimgSize = input.step * input.rows;
    size_t d_opimgSize = output.step * output.rows;

    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc( (void**) &device_input, d_ipimgSize) ); 
    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc( (void**) &device_output, d_opimgSize) ); 

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(device_input, input.data, d_ipimgSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    dim3 Threads(BLOCK_ROWS, BLOCK_COLS);  // 512 threads per block
    dim3 Blocks((input.cols + Threads.x - 1)/Threads.x, (input.rows + Threads.y - 1)/Threads.y);    

    //int check = (input.cols + Threads.x - 1)/Threads.x;
    //printf( "blockx %d", check);

    FilterKernel <<< Blocks, Threads >>> (device_input, device_output, input.rows, input.cols);

    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(output.data, device_output, d_opimgSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    //printf( "num_rows_cuda %d", num_rows);
    //printf("\n");

    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(device_input));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(device_output));

}
```

**main function**

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>

#include <CUDA_wrapper.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{   

    //Read the image from harddisk, into a cv::Mat
    //IplImage *img=cvLoadImage("image.jpg");
    //cv::Mat input(img);
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/Users/OCT/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/MedianFilter/MedianFilter/pic1.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    //IplImage* input = cvLoadImage("G:/Research/CUDA/Trials/OCTFilter/Debug/pic1.bmp");
    if(input.empty())
    {
        cout<<"Image Not Found"<<endl;
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat output(input.rows,input.cols,CV_8UC1);

    // store the different details of the input image like img_data, rows, cols in variables 
    int Rows = input.rows;
    int Cols = input.cols;
    unsigned char* Data = input.data;

    cout<<"image rows "<<Rows<<endl;
    cout<<"image cols "<<Cols<<endl;
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"data "<<(int)Data<<endl;
    cv::waitKey(0);

    // call the device function to take the image as input
    take_input(input, output);

    cv::Mat dest; 

    medianBlur ( input, dest, 3 );

    //Show the input and output
    cv::imshow("Input",input);
    cv::imshow("Output",output);
    cv::imshow("Median blur",dest);

    //Wait for key press
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Comment: I think you did mistaken `threadIdx.x` as rows and `threadIdx.y` as cols. In your kernel setup you wrote `dim3 Threads(BLOCK_ROWS, BLOCK_COLS);`. Therefore `threadIdx.x` will be for rows and `threadIdx.y` will be the cols! In the kernel you used it in the wrong way - `if(x>d_iCols || y>d_iRows)`! Also your calculation of `tid` looks strange to me. `window` is allocated with `window[BLOCK_ROWS*BLOCK_COLS][]` but `tid` is calculated as `tid = threadIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.x;`. In my oppnion `tid` will acces `window` out of bounds and in a wrong way! Add `cudaGetLastError()` after your kernel!

Comment: also, you seem to be confused about datatypes.  Your image appears to consist of `unsigned char` (8-bit) pixels, but you are copying them to `unsigned short` (16-bit) pixels on the device.  Why is the kernel doing everything with `unsigned short` if your pixels are `unsigned char` ?

Comment: @hubs Right, I had a suspicion that I had interchanged the rows with columns, and so, I changed the kernel out-of-bounds-check to `if(x>d_iRows || y>d_iCols)`. However, I don't get how I should index `tid`?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Okay, I corrected the data types - changed every `unsigned short` to `unsigned char`. However, I'm still not sure as to how to index `tid`?

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you intend `x` to represent rows or columns.  When you say 1024x256 I assume you are referring to typical image description which is widthxheight, ie. colsxrows.  If `x` represents rows (not sure?) then a *block-unique* `tid` could be `tid = threadIdx.x *blockDim.y + threadIdx.y`  I'm not sure I would write code that way, but you should be able to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there were a variety of errors and unnecessary complication in your "kernel implementation" file.

You may have better luck with the following:

```
$ cat t376.cu
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DCOLS 1024
#define DROWS 256

typedef struct {
  size_t step;
  size_t rows;
  size_t cols;
  unsigned char *data;
} mat;


// define the threads and grids for CUDA
#define BLOCK_ROWS 32
#define BLOCK_COLS 16

// define kernel dimensions
#define MEDIAN_LENGTH 9

// this is the error checking part for CUDA
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}


__global__ void FilterKernel (unsigned char *d_input_img, unsigned char *d_output_img, int d_iRows, int d_iCols)

{

    unsigned int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned char window[MEDIAN_LENGTH];

    if(col>=d_iCols || row>=d_iRows)
        return;

    window[0]= (row==0||col==0) ? 0 :                 d_input_img[(row-1)*d_iCols+(col-1)];
    window[1]= (row==0) ? 0 :                         d_input_img[(row-1)*d_iCols+col];
    window[2]= (row==0||col==d_iCols-1) ? 0 :         d_input_img[(row-1)*d_iCols+(col+1)];
    window[3]= (col==0) ? 0 :                         d_input_img[row*d_iCols+(col-1)];
    window[4]=                                        d_input_img[row*d_iCols+col];
    window[5]= (col==d_iCols-1) ? 0 :                 d_input_img[row*d_iCols+(col+1)];
    window[6]= (row==d_iRows-1||col==0) ? 0 :         d_input_img[(row+1)*d_iCols+(col-1)];
    window[7]= (row==d_iRows-1) ? 0 :                 d_input_img[(row+1)*d_iCols+col];
    window[8]= (row==d_iRows-1||col==d_iCols-1) ? 0 : d_input_img[(row+1)*d_iCols+(col+1)];

    // Order elements
    for (unsigned int j=0; j<5; ++j)
    {
        // Find position of minimum element
        unsigned char temp = window[j];
        unsigned int  idx  = j;
        for (unsigned int l=j+1; l<9; ++l)
            if (window[l] < temp){ idx=l; temp = window[l];}
        // Put found minimum element in its place
        window[idx] = window[j];
        window[j] = temp;
    }

    d_output_img[row*d_iCols + col] = (window[4]);

}

void take_input(const mat& input, const mat& output)
{

    unsigned char *device_input;
    unsigned char *device_output;

    size_t d_ipimgSize = input.step * input.rows;
    size_t d_opimgSize = output.step * output.rows;

    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc( (void**) &device_input, d_ipimgSize) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc( (void**) &device_output, d_opimgSize) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(device_input, input.data, d_ipimgSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    dim3 Threads(BLOCK_COLS, BLOCK_ROWS);  // 512 threads per block
    dim3 Blocks((input.cols + Threads.x - 1)/Threads.x, (input.rows + Threads.y - 1)/Threads.y);

    //int check = (input.cols + Threads.x - 1)/Threads.x;
    //printf( "blockx %d", check);

    FilterKernel <<< Blocks, Threads >>> (device_input, device_output, input.rows, input.cols);
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(output.data, device_output, d_opimgSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    //printf( "num_rows_cuda %d", num_rows);
    //printf("\n");

    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(device_input));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(device_output));

}

int main(){
  mat input_im, output_im;
  input_im.rows  = DROWS;
  input_im.cols  = DCOLS;
  input_im.step  = input_im.cols;
  input_im.data  = (unsigned char *)malloc(input_im.step*input_im.rows);
  output_im.rows = DROWS;
  output_im.cols = DCOLS;
  output_im.step = input_im.cols;
  output_im.data = (unsigned char *)malloc(output_im.step*output_im.rows);

  for (int i = 0; i < DCOLS*DROWS; i++) {
    output_im.data[i] = 0;
    input_im.data[i] = 0;
    int temp = (i%DCOLS);
    if (temp == 5) input_im.data[i] = 20;
    if ((temp > 5) && (temp < 15)) input_im.data[i] = 40;
    if (temp == 15) input_im.data[i] = 20;
    }

  take_input(input_im, output_im);
  for (int i = 2*DCOLS; i < DCOLS*(DROWS-2); i++)
    if (input_im.data[i] != output_im.data[i]) {printf("mismatch at %d, input: %d, output: %d\n", i, (int)input_im.data[i], (int)output_im.data[i]); return 1;}
  printf("Success\n");
  return 0;
}


$ nvcc -o t376 t376.cu
$ ./t376
Success
$
```

a few notes:

1. I have tested this (not using OpenCV) for the simple case that I have injected in the code.
2. Your usage of `window` was unnecessarily complex.  Note that the way you have it, *each thread* will instantiate its own local copy of `window` independent of, and invisible to, the other threads.  (perhaps you intended to use shared memory here?  But I digress.)
3. Your sorting routine was broken.  I modified it to a version that I think will work.
4. replaced pixel data types with `unsigned char` throughout
5. `x` and `y` were confusing, so I changed them to `row` and `col` which seems less confusing.
6. improved kernel error checking slightly
7. There are many ways to optimize this.  However your sensible goal was to get something working correctly first. So I'll not spend much time on optimizations except to point out the two general areas of shared memory for reuse of the `window` data, and an improved sorting routine.
8. You'll need to modify this appropriately for openCV
9. Note that if you modify it to DROWS = 1024 and DCOLS = 256, it still works.

**EDIT:** after reading your comments that things are still not working, it appears your OpenCV code is not set up properly to feed a single channel 8-bit grayscale (CV_8UC1) image both *to* and *from* your `take_input` function.  The problem arises from this line:

```
cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/Users/OCT/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/MedianFilter/MedianFilter/pic1.bmp",1);
```

The `1` parameter being passed to `imread` specifies a RGB image load. Refer to [imread documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html):

```
Now we call the imread function which loads the image name specified by the first argument (argv[1]). The second argument specifies the format in what we want the image. This may be:

CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED (<0) loads the image as is (including the alpha channel if present)
CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE ( 0) loads the image as an intensity one
CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR (>0) loads the image in the RGB format
```

You might have better luck if you specify `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` there instead of `1`.

Or else you should research how to load a image so that it ends up as a `CV_8UC1` type.

But if you pass that `input` to `take_input` as-is, it surely won't work.

Comment: Your `col x row` explanation is right but, the image dimensions I provided were reversed. The correct dimensions are `cols = 256` and `rows = 1024` (as can be verified from the screenshot). So, I had corrected my kernel implementation along with all the data types but, that did not work. So, I tried your implementation and even that does not work. It does compile but, that is no consolation.

Comment: OK, I've edited the code to include a tested and complete working example not using OpenCV.  It works whether you set cols = 256 or cols = 1024.  You just need to integrate it back into your OpenCV harness.  Or else you'll need to be a little more descriptive than "it does not work".

Comment: Well it does work for the simple image that you created. However, when I input the image which I want to work with in openCV, it turns out to provide the same output. I tried to input another image which is `512x512` and this was the output: http://snag.gy/AzXMZ.jpg . Darn, I really can't figure it out - my openCV code is so simple that I only take the input/output and display it.

Comment: Got it! I realized that I was loading in a color image using openCV. Converted the input to grayscale and it worked!

Comment: It seems your OpenCV is broken to.  Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

in CUDA 6.0, the NPP library now includes an implementation of a median filter for all datatypes and pixel formats.  So if you just want a functional median filter routine, you can call that.  if you want help debugging your kernel, see all the other answers...